# How do I submit the results of this form to a method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, routes

I get a NoMethodError when submitting this form, I've no idea how to get it to work. It's just a password reset form though the Devise gem, and trying the `@user.send_reset_password_instructions` in the console works just fine.

Here's the form in my view:

```
<%= form_tag reset_password_path(:email), :id => 'forgotten_password' do %>
  <%= email_field_tag :email, nil, :placeholder => 'Email address' %>
  <%= submit_tag "Reset password" %>
<% end %>
```

In my routes:

```
get "/dashboard/reset_password/:email" => "docs#reset_password", :as => :reset_password
```

In my controller:

```
def reset_password
  @user = User.where(:email => params[:email]).first
  @user.send_reset_password_instructions
end
```

Here's the error:

```
No route matches [POST] "/dashboard/reset_password/email"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your route needs to have the POST method in it, not GET. And it should be `/email` not `/:email`

```
post "/dashboard/reset_password/email" => "docs#reset_password", :as => :reset_password
```

Answer (score 1):

You defined your route to respond to `GET` requests, and your form is sending a `POST` request. Try changing the method of your route from `get` to `post`

Answer (score 0):

So, part one is to make your route a POST instead of a GET (as mentioned previously). Typically whenever you're sending data to the server and it's causing a change (like setting the reset password token on a user account and sending them an email) you use a POST.

Change your route to look like this:

```
POST "/dashboard/reset_password" => "docs#reset_password", :as => :reset_password
```

*Note: I also dropped the :email part of the path. You don't really need that.*

Part two, you'll need to tweak your form a little. You don't need to pass the :email symbol to the path. I'm not actually sure what that will do for you in this case. You get the email in the params hash in the controller (params[:email]) because you've got an email field in your form.

Change your form to look like this:

```
<%= form_tag reset_password_path, :id => 'forgotten_password' do %>
  <%= email_field_tag :email, nil, :placeholder => 'Email address' %>
  <%= submit_tag "Reset password" %>
<% end %>
```

That should generate the POST form path '/dashboard/reset_password' in your form HTML. When the user clicks on the "Reset password" button on the page the :email field in the form will get submitted to you. Rails will stuff it into the params and your controller method 'reset_password' be able to read it just fine.

You might also want to do some error catching in your controller method. The most common problem with email password reset is that there's a typo in the email and you won't be able to find the user. It's helpful to return a message to the user when that happens.

Good luck!